# Retain ability to pan on y-axis, without zooming d3.js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3.js but have been currently attempting to build a GANTT chart with d3.js v4.

I have managed to add zoom functionality to the graph but I want it to act differently on the y-axis. Currently, I can pan and zoom on the y-axis, but I only want to pan. This is because the zoom is causing problems by having all elements to spread out on the y-axis graph. Is there a simple fix to this problem?

Here are my scales:

```
//Scale xAxis
var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
                .domain([minDate, maxDate])
                .range([0, graphWidth])

//Scale yAxis
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                .domain([1, 10])
                .range([50, 550])
```

Here is my function that runs during a zoom event.

```
function zoom() {
    // re-scale x axis during zoom
   xAxis.transition()
         .duration(0)
         .call(d3.axisTop(xScale).scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale)));

   // re-draw rectangles using new x-axis scale
   var new_xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale);
   var new_yScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale);

   rect
    .attr("x", function(d) { return new_xScale(d.startDate) })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return new_yScale(d.id) - 35})
    .attr("width", function(d) { return new_xScale(d.endDate) - new_xScale(d.startDate) })

  taskInfo
    .attr("y", function(d) { return new_yScale(d.id) })
}
```

Any thoughts?